How to model NiTe2 (011) plane using ASE
I have modeled the (011) plane of NiTe2 using ASE by cutting through bulk ,by the code given below
 from ase.build import surface
from ase.io import read,write
from ase.visualize import view
import sys

s=read('NiTe2-cod1.cif')
slab = surface(lattice=s, indices=[0,1,1],layers =7)

# write the output in a Espresso input with default parameters as saved in as
slab.write('slab_011.pwi')  
view(slab)




The bulk NiTe2 used  is: NiTe2-cod1.cif
The structure i got for 4×2×6 supercell is as follows,
Top view

side view

But when i checked in literature the structure of modeled surface they have given is different ,and is as follows

As you can see in the surface i modeled there is no Ni atoms visible in top view which is contrary to the structure given in the paper.
The paper I am comparing my structure with is:https://doi.org/10.1039/D0EE00666A
So what am I doing wrong?How can i fix it?

I just think in two things: 1- The crystal structure should be the same in order to obtain the same images, and 2- You can peel your surface removing the top layer.

@Campus After peeling of top Te layer and bottom Ni-Te layer it look matching.
